# Can't jump from another module

Tags: angular, router

I'm new at Angular 2. I did everything like in the instructions but something is wrong: I can't load component defined/routed in external module..

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rjzz1S2s762p8NbjkJtA?p=preview) - This code is super easy. Only 3 links and few empty components. (`app` component and module are combined into one app.ts for simplicity)

Please look at **products.module.ts**. There is a line:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: 
  [ 
    RouterModule.forChild(
    [
      { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent }, // <--- this goes to NotFoundComponent :(
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ ProductsComponent ]
})
```

Where am I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `app.module` switch the routing modules

```
imports: 
  [ 
    BrowserModule,
  /*  RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
      { path: '', component: TestComponent },
      { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
    ]),*/
    ProductsModule, //<-- this needs to be above main routing module
    AppRoutingModule     
  ]
```

Since `AppRoutingModule` is above `ProductsModule`  your `/products` route is consumed by `{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },`

Fixed Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/yOewgV8rtNhFJlrTWTaC?p=preview

Comment: @tBlabs Glad I could help :-)